# Set the app's display name in a notification

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter mobile app, using Google Cloud functions and Google Cloud Messaging. Currently testing with IntelliJ Android Emulator.

Anytime a Cloud Function sends a push notification, the app name is the same, as the  `applicationId` entry in `build.gradle`.

And that's bad, as it shows my app name with underscores.

So if the `applicationId` is 'com.secretcompany.my_super_secret_application`, then the app name in the notifications will be my_super_secret_application instead of My Super Secret Application.
(sorry for obfuscating the image, company policy.)
[image]

Is there a way, to set up the display name from the admin SDK in Google Clouds? Or a way to easily change the app name? Or is it just because I am using an emulated device, and once the app will be released to the store the problem will be gone?

This code sends the notification:

```
function sendNotificationToUser(title: string, body: string, userFcm: string) {
    const notificationContent = {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
            badge: '1',
            click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        },
    };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userFcm, notificationContent)
        .then(() => {
            return;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            functions.logger.error("Error in sending notification");
        })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I understood your question correctly, I believe you can change your App name in the Androidmanifest.xml in **" project_name\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml "**

Change the label to the name you want for your App:

```
 <application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="app_name"...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you sure it's not the `project_name/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml `? The one you mentioned does not has those lines.

Comment: yep, changing the parameter you mentioned fixed the problem. Ty.